# Registration Form CSS nav-bar inside a div

Tags: html, css, forms

Hi everyone thank you for taking the time. I am trying to add the nav-bar that is out of place inside of a container. This is the HTML

```
<div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/packages.jpg');"> 

    <div class="wrap-login100 p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-80 p-b-30">

        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav class="nav-bar-outer"> 
                <buttton type="button" class="hamburger-btn"> HERE </buttton>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <form class="login100-form validate-form">
           <!--css form content-->
```

And this is the CSS.

```
[ Nav-Bar ]*/

.nav-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
 }

.nav-bar-outer{
  background-color: #ffbf00;
  padding:5px;
  height:50px;
  width:390px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
 }

 .wrap-login100 {
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
   border-top-left-radius: 0px;
   border-top-right-radius: 0px;

   width: 390px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   overflow: hidden;

   box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -o-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   -ms-box-shadow: 0 3px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.login100-form {
   width: 100%;
}
 
.p-l-55 {padding-left: 55px;}
.p-b-30 {padding-bottom: 30px;}
.p-r-55 {padding-right: 55px;}
.p-t-80 {padding-top: 80px;}
.p-b-37 {padding-bottom: 37px;}
```

So I think because there is padding in the black container the bar is not positioning itself like I would like to how could it fit inside the container without me having to change the padding (since the content inside would get messed up)

[image]

Comment: Please attach a code snippet with your HTML and CSS to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help readers understand and try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this new CSS to your CSS file.

```
.wrap-login100 {
    position: relative;
}
.nav-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 55px;
    right: 55px;
}
.nav-bar-outer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping, but it only centered the bar ,and made the size equal to of one input box